# How to get selected model from multiple loaded models?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I loaded some models using `Autodesk.gltf` and `Scene Builder`.

Is there a way for me to get the model/information from the model I clicked/selected from the viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. using `AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`.

```
 this.viewer.addEventListener(
  Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
  this.onSelection
);

 onSelection(event) {
   const getSelect = event.selections;
   console.log(getSelect);
 }
```

Comment: That's right :) Here's a blog post explaining some of the other APIs/events you may want to use when dealing with aggregated models: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher

Comment: What if I select the object from scene builder? Is it possible to get the threejs property back? I want to get the position, rotation property.

Comment: Oh, if you're trying to get/set the transformation of individual model _objects_, you can access these using the "fragment list". This [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer) provides more info.